# Inverse Triple Laplace Transform of $\frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I want to find the inverse triple Laplace transform of $L^{-1}_{x_{3}} L^{-1}_{x_{2}} L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right]$. I did
\begin{align*} 
L^{-1}_{x_{3}} L^{-1}_{x_{2}} L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right] &= L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right] \right] \right]
\\
&= (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[\frac{1}{a} L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{a}{s^2_{1} + a^2} \right] \right] \right], \ \  a^2 = s^2_{2} + s^2_{3} 
\\
&= (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[\frac{ \sin \left( x_{1} \sqrt{ \left( s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}\right)} \right) }{\sqrt{ \left( s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}\right)}}  \right] \right] 
\\
&= (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[ \frac{ \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \left(x_{1} \sqrt{s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} }{\sqrt{ \left( s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}\right)}} \right] \right]
\\
&\approx (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[ \frac{ x_{1} \sqrt{s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} - \frac{1}{6} \left(x_{1} \sqrt{s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right)^3 }{\sqrt{ \left( s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}\right)}} \right] \right]
\\
&\approx (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[ x_{1} - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 \left( s^2_{2} + s^2_{3} \right) \right] \right]
\\
&\approx (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[ \left( x_{1} - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 s^2_{3} \right) - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 s^2_{3} \right] \right]
\\
&\approx (-1) L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ \left( x_{1} - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 s^2_{3} \right) \delta(x_{2}) - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 \delta^{"}(x_{2}) \right] 
\\
&\approx (-1) \left( \left( x_{1} \delta(x_{3}) - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 \delta^{"}(x_{3}) \right) \delta(x_{2}) - \frac{1}{6} x_{1}^3 \delta^{"}(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3}) \right)
\end{align*}
I am wondering if this solution is correct or not? and if it is incorrect, what should I do to get the correct solution? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The documentation about the definition of multi-dimensional inverse Laplace transform is short (two lines) and unclear. The command `InverseLaplaceTransform[-1/(s1^2 + s2^2 + s3^2), {s1, s2, s3}, {x1, x2, 
  x3}]` results in `-InverseLaplaceTransform[
  InverseLaplaceTransform[Sin[Sqrt[s2^2 + s3^2] x1]/Sqrt[s2^2 + s3^2], 
   s2, x2], s3, x3]`. In any case, the final result should be symmetric in $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Note that this is a cross-post, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488585).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3):

Your result seems incorrect in view of

```
LaplaceTransform[-(x1*DiracDelta[x3]*DiracDelta[x2] - 
1/6*x1^3 DiracDelta''[x3]*DiracDelta[x2] - 
1/6 x1^3*DiracDelta''[x2]*DiracDelta[x3]), {x1, x2, x3}, {s1, s2,  s3}]
```

> `-(1/s1^2) + s2^2/s1^4 + s3^2/s1^4`

Answer (score -2):

I have another way to solve the problem by using the Taylor series of three variables and I am wondering whether it is correct or not:
\begin{align*} 
L^{-1}_{x_{3}} L^{-1}_{x_{2}} L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right] &= L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{s^2_{1} + s^2_{2} + s^2_{3}} \right] \right] \right]
\\
&= L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} + \frac{2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \left[ a(s_{1} - a) + b(s_{2} - b) + c(s_{3} - c) \right] + \ldots \right] \right] \right]
\\
& \approx L^{-1}_{x_{3}} \left[ L^{-1}_{x_{2}} \left[L^{-1}_{x_{1}} \left[ \frac{-1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} + \frac{2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \left[ a(s_{1} - a) + b(s_{2} - b) + c(s_{3} - c) \right] \right] \right] \right] \\
&\approx \frac{-1}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \delta(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3}) \\
& \ \ \ + \frac{2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} \Big[ a \left(\delta^{\prime}(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3}) - a \delta(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3}) \right) \\
& \ \ \ + b \left(\delta(x_{1}) \delta^{\prime}(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3}) - b \delta(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3})  \right) \\
& \ \ \ + c \left(\delta(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta^{\prime}(x_{3}) - c \delta(x_{1}) \delta(x_{2}) \delta(x_{3})  \right) \Big], 
\end{align*}
for arbitrary $a, b, c \in [0, \infty)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\approx$?

Comment: $\approx$ means "approximation" because I took only the first two terms of the Taylor series of three variables.

Comment: Are you using Mthematica software for your question and answer?  If not, this question should be deleted and possibly posted instead in [math.se].

Comment: This was [posted on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488585) before being posted here.